# Connect Docker Containers: Frontend to GraphQL Backend via Docker Compose on the same Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql

Suppose I'm on a host machine with docker-compose running 2 containers/services:

- backend graphql (ports: 8000:8000)
- frontend react (ports: 8081:8081)

In the frontend container, where my react + apollo code lives, I need to set this const:

```
// frontend container code
export const APOLLO = {
    uri: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/graphql' // << not working, what to use here?
};
```

However, the uri value is not able to connect successfully to the backend graphql endpoint. I'm receiving errors such as `Error Network error: request to http://0.0.0.0:8000/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8000`

The containers work fine on their own. I am able to navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:8000`, `http://0.0.0.0:8000/graphql`, `http://0.0.0.0:8081` to interact with them individually. I am also able to enter each container and reach the other via their service name-spaces with `ping backend` or `ping frontend`.

However, when I do `uri: 'http://backend:8000/graphql'` or `uri: 'http://backend/graphql'` in my code, i get the error `Error Network error: only absolute urls are supported`.

On `docker inspect backend`, I get the backend container's IP address as: `'172.18.0.5'`. Which i tried to plug into the uri as `uri: 'http://172.18.0.5/graphql'`, but I get `Error Network error: Network request failed with status 403 - "Forbidden"`

How should I connect backend docker container to the frontend within the code given these scenarios?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the `docker-compose.yml`, Docker version, the host OS, and any supporting external files so we can reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by running the servers locally instead of Docker and found that backend was rejecting frontend entry due to CORS headers not set. Whitelisted frontends' ip and it worked. Tested again in Docker containers with the backend ip `http://172.18.0.5/graphql` and connection was perfect.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: Referring to the container name in the url hostname i.e. `http://backend/graphql` also works thanks to the docker network bridge setup by docker compose. This is a better solution than hardcoding the docker container ip above.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that occurs when node-fetch does not have access to a protocol or hostname

https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/e2603d31c767cd5111df2ff6e2977577840656a4/src/request.js#L125

```js
if (!parsedURL.protocol || !parsedURL.hostname) {
    throw new TypeError('Only absolute URLs are supported');
}
```

Depending on how your graphql backend processes queries, it might be a good idea to log out the URLs for each of your service endpoint and ensure the URL contains a host AND protocol or the fetch will fail.

For myself, the error occurred for me when my host variable was coming back from the ENV for my service endpoints as `undefined`.